# One to many relationhip for 3 models in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have three models User, Question, Answer. User has many Question and Questions has many Answers but CakePhp shows me error in WHERE clause? How to relation with three models?

I'am trying like

User Model

```
var $hasMany = array(
 'Question' => array(
 'className' => 'Question',
 'foreignKey' => false,
 'conditions' => 'Question.user_id = User.id'
 )
);
```

Answer Model

```
var $hasMany = array(
 'Answer' => array(
 'className'=> 'Answer',
 'foreignKey'=> false,
 'conditions'=> array('Question.id = Answer.question_id')
 )
);
```

Answer model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Question' => array(
        'className'=> 'Question',
        'foreignKey'=> false,
        'conditions'=> array('Question.id = Answer.question_id')
    )
);
```

Thanks in advance for your helps. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Why are you setting foreignKey to false and defining (or at least attempting to) equivalent conditions? `CakePhp shows me error in WHERE clause` <- what error? Where is your find call? Also Answer hasMany Answer isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a design problem more than a technical one,

Try this :

**Relations**

> ```
> users - can take/"be taken by" many - exams
>
> exams - contain/"belongs to" many - questions
> ```

**Tables**

> users        : id - etc.
>
> questions    : id - question - category/topic_id etc.
>
> exams        : id - user_id - question_id - answer etc.

& finally use [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)